# cannot get html extension when using handlebars

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js, extension-methods, htmlextensions

sorry this might be a very silly question but I cannot figure it out. So I am using express-handlebars and I want to name my file newpage.handlebars. But it keeps on saving as a text file. However, I want it to be a HTML extension but the name to be newpage.handlebrs. I have my friends file where he did exactly that but he is away so I can't really ask him. Here is a picture of what he did and what I am doing.His file is mypage.handlebars while mine in newpage.handlebars. How should I fix this. Thanks a lot!

[image: file view]

[image: properties]

Answer (score 0):

- Copy your friend's file, and paste it.
- Get the content inside your current `.handlebars` file, and paste inside the new copied file
- Remove your old `.handlebars` file, and rename the copied one to have the name yours had

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what I had to do. But I was wondering how to do it from the start. Guess there's nothing to do. Thanks for the advise.

Comment: @SafwanUllKarim probably there is a way, but since I don't know, and nobody answered yet, I was only trying to help you achieve what you want in a faster way, while you wait someone answer how to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Found it! Turns out the name can be newpage.handlebars. But to get the html extension you need to start of with a  tag. Even with  tag it doesn't work.